# Moment.js: Convert UTC date from database into local time

Tags: c#, javascript, json, datetime, momentjs

I'm attempting to use moment.js to convert my dates on the client side. I'm going to give the exact specifications.

Dates are stored on the server using `DateTime.UtcNow` in C#. They are saved to a database and look like this: `2014-06-02 21:37:40.087`, so approximately 9:37PM in UTC time. I'm in the West Coast of the US so that translates to 2:37PM PST.

When this rows is read from the application layer and sent to the browser in JSON it resolves to this string `"2014-06-03T04:37:40.087Z"`.

What's with the discrepancy in how it's stored in the database vs. how it comes out in JSON text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that even though you are *storing* UTC values, you aren't treating it as UTC when *retrieving* those values from the database.  Make sure your C# `DateTime` values have `DateTimeKind.Utc` after reading, using `DateTime.SpecifiyKind`.

If you'd like to edit your question with some additional details, such as the specific code involved, then I may be able to provide a clearer answer.

Comment: Matt you were exactly right. When retrieving the date from the DB I was not using `DateTime.SpecifyKind()` before sending them to the browser. Do you know of any way to make the default "kind" of a DateTime UTC for an entire application, or is this not possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible.  Each `DateTime` value is independent.  You may wish to read [What's Wrong with DateTime Anyway](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), [More Fun with DateTime](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime.aspx), and [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).  You might also consider [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) as an alternative.